# "If this isn't flying, I don't know what is." Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, pronouns, sentence-meaning

> If this isn't flying, I don't know what is.

The meaning I'm trying to achieve is that

> If this isn't flying, I don't know what else would be

Instead of

> If this isn't flying, I don't know what **it** is

Since, in this, ***it*** makes people think I'm referring to the object referred to by ***this***

Thanks to **The Photon** for pointing the error out in my interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If this isn't flying, I don't know what flying is
>
> If this isn't flying, I don't know what it is

Neither of these mean the same thing as "If this isn't flying, I don't know what is".

A better way to expand the usual expression would be, "If this isn't flying, then there's no other experience that could be called flying".

> The meaning I'm trying to achieve is that
>
> > If this isn't flying, I don't know what flying is

If this is the meaning you want, then there's nothing wrong with using this sentence to express it. It's just not quite the same meaning as the more common (possibly cliche) expression.

Comment: Just realised what I posted as the meaning wasn't actually what I wanted to mean. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Ending a sentence with **is** or **are** is perfectly fine. Hence, the meaning is achieved in the sentence.

For sources, you can check it [**here**](https://www.englishforums.com/English/EndingSentence/bzvhzv/post.htm)